# Django message framework and login_required

Tags: django

I'm using the Django Message Framework to show messages to users as well as the `@login_required` decorator on one of my views. So if a user tries to access a certain view without being logged in, they get kicked to the login page. How would I go about adding an error message to the login page saying "In order to do ... you must be logged in". I can't add it in the view like you normally would because the non-logged in user would never get to there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's not any obvious way. The only thing that springs to mind is to write your own version of the decorator that puts a message into the session before redirecting, then get the login template to display the message from the session.

You'd need to use the code in `django.contrib.auth.decorators`, in particular the `user_passes_test` function - the bit to add the message would have to go before `return HttpResponseRedirect`.

Answer (score 26):

It took me a while to figure out a nice way of doing this, but I think I have an implementation, based on the answer of Daniel Roseman

First thing I did was creating a decorator that sets messages when a user is not logged in, exactly like login_required.

So I wrote login_required_message:

```
try:
    from functools import wraps
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.functional import wraps  # Python 2.4 fallback.

from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

from django.contrib import messages

default_message = "Please log in, in order to see the requested page."

def user_passes_test(test_func, message=default_message):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    setting a message in case of no success. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not test_func(request.user):
                messages.error(request, message)
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator

def login_required_message(function=None, message=default_message):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated, #fixed by removing ()
        message=message,
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

With this implementation you can now annotate your view methods like this:

```
from decorators import login_required_message
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required_message(message="You should be logged in, in order to see the index!")
@login_required
def index(request):
    pass
```

Now first the message will be set, then the redirect will be performed.

However I actually don't want to add the login_required_message decorator everywhere. It would be much nicer to have only one decorator. So lets chain them (simply add this to your decorator.py file after login_required_message):

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def login_required_message_and_redirect(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None, message=default_message):

    if function:
        return login_required_message(
            login_required(function, redirect_field_name, login_url),
            message
        )

    return lambda deferred_function: login_required_message_and_redirect(deferred_function, redirect_field_name, login_url, message)
```

It took me a while to figure out this last line; but lambda's to the rescue!

Now you can replace the two decorators with only login_required_message_and_redirect: Almost there! Since actually I want to use this new login_required_message-method everywhere, I add a monkey-patch for login_required and it is used everywhere (again add to the bottom of the decorators.py file)!

```
from django.contrib.auth import decorators
setattr(decorators, 'login_required', login_required_message_and_redirect)
```

which allows me to call:

```
# a message will appear, since login_required is monkey patched
@login_required
def logout(request):
    pass 

# or customize the message per view
@login_required(message="You should be logged in message! Available after monkey patch")
def index(request):
    pass
```

Comment: I love this solution, only flaw: I couldn't get the monkey-patch to work. But that's no problem, as my current project is very small (I had to replace 8 annotations, all in one file...)
Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I still have it 10 years later.  Here is the solution I came up with.  It's kind of hacky but it's only 7 lines of code including the decorator.  You use 2 functions.

The first is mapped to the URL path.  It checks to see if the user is logged in.  If the user is not logged in, it sets a message.  Regardless of the user's login state, it returns with a call to the second function.

The second function does what the standard view would have done but it has the decorator on it.

```
def content(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        messages.warning(request, 'You must log in to view the course content.')
    return content2(request)

@login_required
def content2(request):
    return render(request, 'path/template.html')
```

I am assuming that your log in template already displays messages.

Like I said, it's a bit of a hack but it works really well.

I am using Django version 3.0.6

Comment: this is actually pretty cool, but it does mean that every view would need two functions. perhaps this is easier if views are classes?

Comment: Thanks.  In the app I developed this was the only view that needed 2 functions since the others are not displaying this message to the non-authenticated user.  I guess every view that requires the user to be authenticated would need 2 functions.  Unfortunately, I can't yet address your question about classes but I suspect that you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

#Create a decorators.py and use the below code

`````
from django.contrib import messages


def login_required(fn):
    def wrapper(request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            messages.success(request,"Sorry! You are not logged in")
            return redirect("login")
        else:
            return fn(request,*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper


#Import the custom decorator on your views
from app_name.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request,"Successfully logged out!!!")
    return redirect('login')````

Note: @login_required will work only on function function based views and if you are using class based views, you can use method decorators like the example below:
from app_name.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class YourClassBasedView(TemplateView):


Hope this will help you!
`````

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

I know it's old but it can still help others

I think to redirect an unconnected user to the login page and at the same time send a message you can proceed as follows:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def views(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,
                             'You must be logged in')
        return redirect('your_login_views')
    else:
        # do smothing
        return redirect(request, 'your_page.html')
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not handle the redirect back to the first content after the user logs in.  They will be redirected to the path specified in LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.

Answer (score -4):

Try using this: http://code.google.com/p/django-session-messages/

or use Django 1.2 (currently in Beta) and the messages framework: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#ref-contrib-messages