# Diplay error message

Tags: django

I have a site, that has a submit form, but one must be logged in for that. And if the user is not logged in, it redirects it to the login page. And this all fine. My question is, what do I do to display the error message, "You must be logged to submit.", if the user is not logged in and tries to submit the form, but has to display the normal login page if not.
Thank you.

Comment: are you talking about ajax form submits ? `@login_required` would only redirect you, It would not show the message

Comment: oh no. Then, then how do i do, if not @login_required to display the error message. Will, is_authenticated() work?

Comment: look into ajax form submit. You can display the message right there.

Comment: Okay. I'm just learning this whole web thing, and after the django polls tutorial, im learning from one book, which i have yet to cover a lot, so, after some chapter i'm gona reach to the ajax part! Hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use decorator `@login_required`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/your/login/url')
def your_view(request):
    # your view code here
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i have @login_required in my views. Its just that, how can i show the error message when i redirect the page if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Ah so you need something else, not `@login_required`. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723842/django-message-framework-and-login-required?rq=1