# how to use django message framework for @login_required to show message

Tags: django, django-templates, django-login, django-messages

I am using @login required decorator in my most of views so what I want is to use message in my login page telling user if you want to open that page you have to login first so how I can achieve that I know I cannot achieve that on my views so anyone does that and know how to do please tell me how to achieve that if a user redirected to login because of @login required I want to show message please login to continue

I also looked on some of the same question I am looking for answer which got implemented on all the login required decorator so I don't have to change code everywhere it already got implemented in all of the login required decorator in my whole app

my login view

```
def my_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            remember_me = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if not remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')
                else:
                    request.session.set_expiry(1209600)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')
            else:
                return redirect('accounts:login')
        else:
            return redirect('accounts:register')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, "login.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: did this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723842/django-message-framework-and-login-required

Comment: i checked those anwser earlier i have to change in all the views but i am lookin for a anwser which got implemented in my all of the views where @login required i don't have to change everywhere becuase i have a very big project file so it doesn't make sense and some of them are outdated

Comment: Can you share what you have already implemented?

Comment: @bdbd i didn't implement anything because i didn;t know how to do that what i want to say suppose my view has login_required decorator so
if a user is authencticated he/she can view the page but if user is not authenticated he/she will redirected to login page because of login_required right so when if user is redirected because of login required i want to show massage.error (request,  'in oder to continue please login ') on my login page i hope you get my point

Comment: Does the [answer by LvanderRee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777372/14991864) on the question linked by [amadou sow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939546/how-to-use-django-message-framework-for-login-required-to-show-message#comment121836335_68939546) not work?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat in that anwser he create a custom decorator and liked it login required and i am looking anwser for built in decorator there must be a way i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

In your view, check the query parameter "next", as if the user is redirected to the login view, it would come with the `?next=/whatever` in the URL. You can do

```py
if 'next' in request.GET:
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
```

Solution 2 (not recommended, this makes it confusing to debug for others):

Python being a dynamic language, you can hijack the behaviour of `login_required` with your version.

in your `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` and maybe `asgi.py` you would need to "monkey patch" the `login_required` decorator.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import decorators

def my_login_required(...):
    # you can look at the implementation in the answer by LvanderRee mentioned in the comments

decorators.login_required = my_login_required
```

Now, because these files will be the first code to execute before Django even starts, this will replace the built-in `login_required` with your version.

Comment: i didn't understand the first one can please elaborate more

Comment: like if you have a view that needs login, but the user isn't logged in, by default django will redirect you to the login view with the `next` query param, for example `/profile` needs login, and the user is not logged in,  django will take him to `https://example.com/login/?next=/profile`, so in your view, you can check `"next" in request.GET`

Comment: it means i have to pass that query parameter in every view so there is no way to do change in one file and executed in all views where @login required is passed

Comment: I'd imagine you would do this only in your `my_login` view, not on every single view.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578882/how-to-specify-the-login-required-redirect-url-in-django), using multiple answers, to redirect to another page, either:

Set `LOGIN_URL` in settings.py. This is the URL that Django will redirect to if a user that's not yet logged in attempts to log in.

or Inline:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/example url you want redirect/') #redirect when user is not logged in
def myview(request):
    do something
    return something #returns when user is logged in
```

Of course, you still need to have the login view setup.

If you want to check if the user is authenticated in the HTML, you can use the templating system: (For clarity this is something I just whipped up right now, it's not from the Stack Overflow post mentioned above)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
// Display something if authenticated maybe
{% else %}
// Display something like "You are not logged in etc"
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If you set LOGIN_URL in settings it's applied as the default for all views. View the accepted answer on the SO post I shared

Comment: bro you didi n't read the question properly please read it then anwser