# how to do sorting of a search result item in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

i have search field i want to give user sorting option so user can do sorting for price low to high to low in the search result but unable to achieve that
my view

```
class search_item(View):
    def get(self, request):
        search_item = request.GET.get('search')
        if search_item:
            items = Item.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search_item)|Q(color__icontains=search_item))
            sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", "l2h") 
            if sort_by == "l2h":
                item = items.order_by("price")
            elif sort_by == "h2l":
                item = items.order_by("-price")
            return render(request, 'search_result.html', {'items':item})
```

it does the search but unable to do sorting what wrong in my code

html

```
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="?sort=l2h">Low To High</a></li>
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="?sort=h2l">High To Low</a></li>
```

my model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='our_items')
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    swag = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    male = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    female = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    unisex = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    first = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    second = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    third = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default='Black')
    material = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='Plastic' )
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False,)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_items_by_id(ids):
        return Item.objects.filter(id__in = ids)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my url

```
path('search-result/',search_item.as_view(),name='search')
```

error when i to do sorting by reuslted item price
The view products.views.search_item didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy2.0\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy2.0\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 188, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy2.0\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 309, in check_response
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /search-result/
Exception Value: The view products.views.search_item didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

view in which sorting work perfectly fine

```
class Product(View):
    def get(self, request, subcategory_id):
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategories, pk=subcategory_id)

        sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", "l2h") 
        if sort_by == "l2h":
           products = subcategory.products.order_by("price")
        elif sort_by == "h2l":
           products = subcategory.products.order_by("-price")
        sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", "newest")
        if sort_by == "unisex":
            products = subcategory.products.order_by("-unisex")
        elif sort_by == "newest":
            products = subcategory.products.order_by("-update_at")
        sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", "male")
        if sort_by == "male":
            products = subcategory.products.order_by("-male")
        elif sort_by == "female":
            products = subcategory.products.order_by("-female")

        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        return render (request, 'products.html',{"subcategory_list" : products, 'category_list': category_list })
```

Comment: Exactly what URL do you vist?

Comment: Are you saying that low to high works but high to low doesn't? Or that it doesn't sort by price at all? Is `sort_by` the correct value in each case?

Comment: @jarmod sorting doesn't work at all for search result

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added

Comment: What does `items` contain after the `filter` call? What does `item` contain after `item = items.order_by(...)`? Maybe update your question with evidence that this is not working (just include key and price columns, for example).

Comment: @jarmod add the required data

Comment: I don't know Django well enough to understand how things are connected, but your get() method implicitly returns None if search_item is falsey. Have you done any debugging here? Are you sure that your filter/order_by code is actually executing? At the very least, your get function should probably return something if search_item is falsey or `raise Http404(...)` or some other HTTP response object.

Comment: @jarmod i am doing same type of sorting in items and there everything work perfectly fine and same thing i want to implement here i f you wanna look that view i added that

Comment: They're slightly different. Your product/view/get code is not conditional. Your search_item/view/get code *is* conditional - it's conditional on search_item being truthy. Please log the value of search_item and also log the value of `items` (after the filter call) and `item` (after the order_by call).

Comment: @jarmod so what do you suggest for soting product in search result except this better way

Comment: Can you add the requested debugging info?

Comment: @jarmod thank for your help and effort i figured it out by myself thank you

Comment: What was the problem? Was search_item falsey, or some other cause?

Comment: problem in that when i click to that link it referesh the page return with empty search result so there is no search item to sort with

Comment: I think you're saying "yes, search_item is falsey". I can only recommend that you add logging to your applications going forward and you get comfortable with debugging your app using logs. Log the important paths and variables.

Comment: @jarmod maybe this not the right way to asking for help but i also want to know about this question which i posted i didn't find any useful article maybe you know it but if you want you can ignore this

Comment: this is the link if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/q/68939546/14777930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error message is key:

> products.views.search_item didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

It's telling you that your `products.views.search_item` method returned None. How can it return None? It returns None, implicitly, when `search_item` has a falsey value and it entirely skips the reading/sorting of the items. And that happens when the `search` parameter is absent (or empty).