# Django: How to add next to manual login redirect?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I have a view:

```
def create_something(request):
    ...
```

I want to redirect to login if a person isn't logged in. Normally I'd use:

```
@login_required
def create_something(request):
    ...
```

**but ...**
I want to add a message before the redirect.

I wanted to do it like this:

```
def create_something(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.info(request, 'You must be logged in to create a thing .')
        return redirect('login')
    ...
```

However, that doesn't include a `?next` in the url to go back to the page I was going to.

So my question is:

**How would you manually redirect back to the login page WITH a manually added `?next` query?**

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723842/django-message-framework-and-login-required) might be helpful

Comment: That is similar to what I was looking for, but I think Wilem's answer (marked as answer on this question) actually even answers that in a more simple format. Plus different keywords (at least how they formulated in my head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L10-L35) of the [**`@user_passes_test`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) and determine how such redirect is done.

In the source code we see:

> ```
> # ⋮
> path = request.get_full_path()
> from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
> return redirect_to_login(path, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
> ```

We can thus mimic this behaviour with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
from django.urls import reverse

def create_something(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.info(request, 'You must be logged in to create a thing �.')
        path = request.get_full_path()
        return redirect_to_login(path, reverse('login'))
    # …
```

Here the [**`.redirect_to_login(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.redirect_to_login) will thus produce a redirect where the querystring will contain a key `next=…` where `next` is associated with the path.

You should use `path = request.build_absolute_uri()` in case the schema or hostname.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know those existed. Thanks Willem!

Answer (score -1):

Just add the below decorator to your function:

```
 @login_required(login_url='/console/login')
```

The 'console/login' is the url path you want to redirect to. Alternatively, you can add the url to your settings.py file.

```
 LOGIN_URL = 'url'
```

Comment: That wasn't my question. I know how to set the next url, but not when using `redirect('login')` when the login is already setup in the way that you have.